# SSH user (not root) cannot login by pubkey

Tags: ssh

**sshd.configt**

- PubkeyAuthentication yes
- AuthorizedKeysFile   .ssh/authorized_keys2

**userfile**

1. drwx------  myadmin myadmin 4096 Jun 26 14:51 /home/myadmin/.ssh
2. -rw------- myadmin myadmin  779 /home/myadmin/.ssh/authorized_keys2

Answer (score 0):

The newly added user is locked. Unlock myadmin with "passwd -f -u myadmin" ,then it work normal.